# Cursor select on 2nd Primary key on db2 sql field for embedded positional value - Unable to determine most efficient for longterm design

Tags: sql, performance, db2, primary-key, substr

I have a SQL DB2 table where the first two fields are the primary keys (not including the third field which is date/time stamp). The table was designed by another team with the intent to make it generic. I was brought into the project after the key value for the second field was coded for when it was inserted onto the table. This leads me to this: We now have to do a cursor select with a WHERE clause that includes the first primary key – and then for the second primary key it must be for only when it is a specific value in position 21 for 8 bytes. (And we will always know what that value will be for the second field.) The second field is a generic 70 byte field (alphanumeric). My question is should we use a LIKE wildcard for the WHERE clause statement for the second primary field condition or instead a SUBSTR since we know the position of the value? I ask because I have done an EXPLAIN yet I do not see a difference between the two (neither does my database analyst). And this is for a few million records for a 1300 byte long table. However, my concern is volume of the data on the table will grow on various systems. Therefore performance may become an issue. Just right now it is hard to measure the difference between LIKE and SUBSTR. But I would like to do my due diligence and code this for long term performance. And if there is a third option, please let me know.

Comment: Think of an extra generated column which holds the substring. This would be optimal as the value would be generated automatically by Db2 on insert and it could be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU difference between a `SUBSTR` and a `LIKE` will be minimal. What might be more important is the filter factor estimate in the explain. You might want to use a statistical view over the table to help the optimizer here. In that case the `SUBSTR` operator will be better as you would include that as a column in the stats view.

Alternatively, a generated column based on the `SUBSTR` would also provide the better stats, and you could include the column in an index too.